# Advice designing a stock management database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am developing a webapp for my business, a mobile phone repair shop. The problem I have is I don't know how exactly to implement a way to manage the parts inventory.

Here what i have now:

```
{Parts(id, name)} 
{Inventory(id, part_id, initial_qty, current_qty, initial_price, current_price)} 
{Operations(id, name)} 
{Inventory_Operation(id, inventory_id, operation_id, explanation, qty, price)}
```

I need to have a possibility to add inventory, sell inventory, add inventory to repairs, mark inventory as bad, return inventory.

I am developing using MySQL.

LE

[image: ERD]

As i mentioned before, the app will manage all of the shop repairs, i have the rest figured out, but this inventory management part of the database i cannot get a clear image. 
When i buy parts from suppliers i need to add them to the inventory (they dont have serial numbers, i only need the quantity), then when i do a repair, and use a part, then the inventory for that part must be decreased, sometimes after a repair the client comes back because the part is not ok, and i need to offer warranty so i need to mark that part as defective in the inventory, other times i do the repair and the client declines to pay so i must return the part to the inventory. The other problem is, i can receive the same part with different price, or different supplier.

LE 2
I have made the whole app db diagram, the diagram is more or less accurate.
[image]

Comment: It's hard to suggest a database design based on the information you gave. It would help if you further described the _entities_ that you want to store data for, as well as how they relate to one another.

Comment: This question has a good example of a thorough project description in the italicized text: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/99363/64482

Comment: @JoeBorysko added some more information, hope it helps.

Comment: You mentioned that you don't have serial numbers for individual parts, and that you only need the quantity. If you need to mark a particular part as defective though, you **would** need a way to reference that part. Are you sure there's no unique number you can use to identify an individual part?

Comment: Also, are you asking for suggestions for the database model, or are you only trying to understand your current model?

Comment: No the serial number is irrelevant, since i don't need to know witch part is defective, only the quantity. This is the diagram i thought of, but i am no expert, so maybe the experts shine some light on the matter.

Comment: I can't really comment on how good your model is as a whole because I still don't feel like I have enough knowledge about how what kind of data you're wanting to store. Nothing pops out at me as being glaringly wrong.